# How to Change Parcel Bundler's Compiled CSS Links' Order in the Compiled HTML

Tags: reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4, sass, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize Bootstrap's SASS variables so I need to link Bootstrap's CDN in my uncompiled HTML but every time I use Parcel to bundle everything, the resulting compiled HTML has the link for the CDN come after the auto-generated CSS link for my customizations (the compiled CSS of my SASS that was imported on my index.js) which in turn resets everything to their default styling.

[image]

I'm new to Parcel and I was wondering if there's a way for me to change the order of the generated CSS link to come after the CDN link in the compiled HTML? So that I won't need to rearrange them every time I compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same issue, can't find any related docs. As a temporary(?) solution I moved the css import away from my `App.jsx` file to another `<link>` tag in the HTML, after the bootstrap link (same goes for css-reset).

Before:

```
// App.jsx
import './main.css';
```

After:

```
// index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.com/path/to/bootstrap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

According to Parcel's docs this should also work with `sass`, `less` and `stylus`
(e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.less" />`.

[Parcel/less docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/less/#example-usage)